# Fused location provider singleton example?

Tags: android, fusedlocationproviderapi

Hi is it possible to create a fused location provider singleton which can be used to get the last location from many activities?

In addition how would i maintain an Google Api Client instance across these activities in terms of connect and disconnect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible. You will want to implement the private constructor/ getInstance() combo --

```
/**
 * Private constructor.
 */   
private GPSPlotter(Context theContext) {
    initializeInstance();
    initializeFields(theContext);
    buildApiClient();
    connectClient();
}

/**
 * Returns an instance of the GPS Plotter.
 */
public static GPSPlotter getInstance(Context theContext) {

    if (gpsPlotterInstance == null)
        return new GPSPlotter(theContext);
    else
        return gpsPlotterInstance;

}
```

I'm fairly certain passing Context as a parameter to model objects breaks with Android convention, but structuring your code like this should work.